# Fiddler How not to proxy a URL ？

Tags: fiddler, httpwatch

I use the simulator agent Fiddler,

but I don't want some URL to go to the proxy.

Like what：

- http://a.com  `Agent`
- http://b.com  `Agent`
- http://127.0.0.1  `Not agent`

I hope 'http://127.0.0.1' does not pass fiddler agent

---

When I debug the simulator.

The simulator app accesses `127.0.0.1`, and this address is proxied by`fiddler`.

Actually I don't want to proxy him, Because `127.0.0.1` is handled by this APP itself.

but I need to proxy other non-local URLs, such as ``` a.com`` b.com ``` ...

Comment: Could you try to reformulate the question to make it clearer, and provide more context?

Comment: When I debug the simulator. 

The simulator app accesses `127.0.0.1`, and this address is proxied by` fiddler`. 

Actually I don't want to proxy him, Because `127.0.0.1` is handled by this APP itself.

but I need to proxy other non-local URLs, such as `a.com`` b.com` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control which requests should not be sent through the Fiddler proxy, you can use the `Tools -> Options -> Connections -> Bypass Fiddler for URLs that start with:` setting. For example, to ignore localhost you can edit the setting to:

```
<-loopback>;*127.0.0.1;*localhost
```

After changing the setting, you must **reattach Fiddler** as system proxy, e.g. by stopping and then starting capturing with the `Capturing` button, or just by restarting Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped me to bypass http2 requests which are currently not supported by fiddler classic. This allowed me inspect other http 1 traffic and didn't let my application crash since http2 traffic was no lonmger blocked.